# Why am i getting this exception? StringIndexOutOfBounds

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class romanNumeral {
public String roman_Numeral; 
public int roman_NumeralLength, decimalValue = 0;

public romanNumeral() 
{
   retrieveInput();
   loopThroughString();
   System.out.println(decimalValue);
}
public void retrieveInput() 
{
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter roman numeral: \n");
    roman_Numeral = console.next();
    roman_Numeral = roman_Numeral.toUpperCase();
    roman_NumeralLength = roman_Numeral.length();

}
public void loopThroughString()
{
    for(int i=0;i<=roman_NumeralLength;i++) 
    {
        if(roman_Numeral.charAt(i) == 'M')
            decimalValue+=1000;
        else if(roman_Numeral.charAt(i) == 'D')
            decimalValue+=500;
        else if(roman_Numeral.charAt(i) == 'C')
            decimalValue+=100;
        else if(roman_Numeral.charAt(i) == 'L')
            decimalValue+=50;
        else if(roman_Numeral.charAt(i) == 'X')
            decimalValue+=10;
        else if(roman_Numeral.charAt(i) == 'V')
            decimalValue+=5;
        else if(roman_Numeral.charAt(i) == 'I')
            decimalValue+=1;



    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    romanNumeral program = new romanNumeral();


}

}
```

here is the error thrown

```
Enter roman numeral: 
M
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:    String index out of range: 1
at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:646)
at romanNumeral.loopThroughString(romanNumeral.java:25)
at romanNumeral.<init>(romanNumeral.java:9)
at romanNumeral.main(romanNumeral.java:46)
```

The decimal values of the Roman numerals are:

1. M = 1000
2. D = 500
3. C = 100
4. L = 50
5. X = 10
6. V = 5
7. I = 1

can anyone help please? The meaning of this program is to get a roman numeral from a user than convert it to decimal value. any input is greatly appreciated :)....surrounded with try/catch to handle the exception it handled than output the correct value....so why am I getting this exception and how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is your problem.

```
 for(int i=0;i<=roman_NumeralLength;i++)
```

NumeralLength would give you the number of characters in the string. However, the largest legal index is always the length()-1.

Thus, you are trying to access a character that is outside of the String, resulting in the indexOutOfBounds, as indexes always count 0 as a place.

To Fix.

```
 for(int i=0;i<=roman_NumeralLength-1;i++)
 // Just insert (-1)...Or change the comparator to "<".
 //Both give you the same result
```

Comment: @Nathan Marotta I gave you your fix and attempted to explain to you why you are trying to access an index that is non existent. If you can't understand it.. let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand...thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 1):

You are going one over you Strings length

```
for(int i=0;i<=roman_NumeralLength;i++) //less than or equals too
```

should be

```
for(int i=0;i<roman_NumeralLength;i++) //less than
```

Answer (score 1):

just remove the equal sign from your condition.

```
for(int i=0;i<roman_NumeralLength;i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loop control variables (i) are going up to `roman_NumeralLength` - which is an out of bounds index (since the max index of a string/list is len - 1 - remember the first index is 0).

Try using `i < roman_NumeralLength`  as the loop conditions instead.